# determine which EditText field is selected on focus

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table with multiple rows, each containing an EditText which corresponds to a dimension. I want to have some sort of listener that will return whichever EditText is currently selected. Can this be done with `getCurrentFocus();` or `onFocusChange();`?

My idea is to have the user select/focus the dimension field they want edited, and then completing the field using an output slope/angle from the device's gyroscope when a "write data" button is pressed. I'd probably do this using `selected_dimension_edittext.setText(gyro_value);`

Comment: what r u going to so with seleted editext? u wanna listen while it is selected or after focus move to next edittext?

Comment: @DIVA I'm planning on changing the value using `x.setText();` using  a button and a gyroscope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can know which EditText has Focus by the ID of the view like this:

```
    EditText edText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText edText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    OnFocusChangeListener mFocusChangeListener = new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(hasFocus){ //Check if View has focus
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.editText1: {
                        //Code A
                    } break;
                    case R.id.editText2: {
                        //Code B
                    } break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    edText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    edText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
```

Comment: Yep, this works! The method's large since I have ~20 dimensions per ramp, but it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the editTexts are in a ArrayList you could pass a Tag to each editText which is the index. 
For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<editTextList.size();i++){
    editTextList.get(i).setTag(i);
}
```

Then you can check with a listener (textChangedListener or TextWatcher-->http://lecturesnippets.com/android-textchanged-listener-textwatcher/) which EditText is changed or selected by reading the tag. Just iterate through your editTextList  and call the setText()-Method if the edit text has the selected tag.

Comment: They aren't in a list, how could I go about doing that? I currently have them initializing within the code, they're dynamic based on the parent ramp style selected (each ramp type has a different set of dimensions associated).

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want. Please have a look at my edited answer

Comment: I updated the OP with (hopefully) a better description of what I'm trying to do.